# How to make in-game purchase items tab, appear directly on the play store page?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I came across this screenshot of in-game purchase items, being shown and buyable directly from the Playstore page of the game. But I can't seem to find this tab on my playstore.

[image: in-game items tab]

Here is the same page but on my playstore.

[image: playstore no tab]

Comment: The top screenshot looks like the web version of Play Store, not the app?

Comment: That's not the web version afaik, as you can't buy in app purchases using the web version of Playstore, and the UI isn't identical